# Running web-application offline on android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

A while ago I created an ASP.NET MVC Web Application for android devices. The application also used jQuery mobile to set up navigation etc.

At the moment, the application is simply being hosted and the androids webview accesses it that way.

The application works as expected, but I was wondering, is it possible to store the MVC web-app on the phone/integrate it into the apk?

I would like to be able to have it run the web-pages while the device is offline. I know it is possible to run simple HTML in the webview but I haven't been able to find anything about something like an ASP.NET MVC web-app. Is this done using phonegap?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly with PhoneGap, from the [PhoneGap FAQ](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/)

```
Q: Can you use PHP/ASP/JSF/Java/.NET with PhoneGap?

A: A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets,
etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language.
This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access existing business processes
while the device is connected to the Internet.
```

So if you are going the PhoneGap route, you'll have to write it in HTML/CSS/JavaScript. However if you more comfortable in .NET and C# then there is always [Xamarin Android](http://xamarin.com/android) which has a free starter version that you can try out. Do realize though that if you go that route it will be a mobile app and not a wrapped ASP.NET app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I am aware it will most likely be a phone app -  I just wanted to be able to do most of the UI using some UI Kits and html/javascript so that it can be integrated to other phone platforms more easily without having to rewrite the entire app and making it easier to update.

Comment: @BASmith If you already familiar with HTML/JavaScript go with PhoneGap. As you don't describe the app, just be aware that if you start getting into performance issues (webkit on older versions of Android) you might want to look at native or other third party solutions such as Xamarin.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input. What are your thoughts on UI kits such as flat ui? http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/ Is it possible to implement them without the use of phonegap? and if not, it should more easily integrate with phonegap as it's only html/css/javascript correct?

Comment: @BASmith I'm going to refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530051/phonegap-bootstrap-or-jquery-mobile. Jon's answer more or less covers my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think what you want to do is serve your data via a web service (MVC4 web api is pretty simple to setup). Then you'd consume that data with your android app and you could more easily cache that data for offline use.

Comment: Well, the first application I created uses an online service and database so it will need to remain online. I wish to create another app now but this time I want the app to be able to run while the device isn't connected to the internet (if needed) and I still wish to still create it using ASP.NET MVC.